# Extract sub array resulting key=id and value=name in CakePHP

Tags: php, arrays, cakephp

I have this nested array:

```
Array
(
    [id] => 1
    [name] => Group 1
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => Group 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [name] => Group 2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 7
            [name] => Group 7
        )

)
```

And I would like to extract sub arrays `[0]`, `[1]`, and `[2]` in one single array BUT following this format:

```
array(
[id] => [name]
)
```

In other words I would like to have this result:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Group 1
    [2] => Group 2
    [7] => Group 7
)
```

*Note: I tried with `Set::classicExtract($my_array['Group'], '{n}.name');` but I can't figure out how to get `group.id` as a key for my array. Any guidance will be appreciated.

Comment: try `array_column` see more http://php.net/array_column

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

(Here I first [`array_filter()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) all values out, which don't have a numeric key. After this I simply [`array_combine()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php) the `id` column with the `name` column which I get with [`array_column()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php))

```
<?php

    $result = array_filter($arr, function($k){
        return is_numeric($k);
    }, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY);

    $result = array_combine(array_column($result, "id"), array_column($result, "name"));  

    print_r($result);

?>
```

output:

```
Array ( [1] => Group 1 [2] => Group 2 [7] => Group 7 )
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out in case if someone else will be interested. Thanks a lot for the quick answers but I was looking on a solution using `CakePHP`.

```
Set::combine($my_array, '{n}.id', '{n}.name'); did the trick, cheers!
```